# Basename detects an extra operand if I use it with find

Tags: files, find, basename

I try to execute basename via find like this:

```
find ./test_folder -type f -exec basename {} +
```

But I get the following error:

```
basename: extra operand './test_folder/test/file.crt'
```

Why I get this though?

Answer (score 4):

[POSIX `basename`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/basename.html) only supports this:

```
basename string [suffix]
```

What happens when providing more than two strings¹ is not specified by POSIX but in most if not all implementations results in a syntax error such as the *`extra operand`* one you're getting.

But even two strings are too many in your case because the second one would be interpreted as a `suffix` to remove. You don't want to specify `suffix`, so with POSIX `basename` you are limited to this:

```
basename string
```

i.e. to one string per invocation of `basename`. The syntax to invoke a separate `basename` for each pathname from `find` is:

```
find … -exec basename {} \;
```

(read [*Understanding the `-exec` option of `find`*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705/108618) to get the difference between `;` and `+`).

The GNU, ast-open, toybox and FreeBSD implementations of `basename` at least support `-a` (aliased to `--multiple` in GNU `basename` and `--all` in ast-open's) that allows them to work with `-exec … +` of `find`. With this option no operand is interpreted as a `suffix` to remove (use `-s …` if you need to remove suffixes). Example:

```
find … -exec basename -a {} +
```

But if you're on a GNU system, your `find` already has the capability to print the basename (tail) of the found files (and has had it decades before GNU `basename` added `-a`/`--multiple`) via its `-printf` predicate:

```
find … -printf '%f\n'
```

In zsh recursive globbing, you can use the `:t` modifier (from csh's history and parameter expansion from the late 70s) in a glob qualifier to get the `t`ail of those paths:

```
print -rC1 -- test_folder/**/*(ND.:t)
```

(with also `N`ullglob, `D`otglob qualifiers and `.` as the equivalent of `find`'s `-type f`).

---

<sup>¹ Strictly speaking, [like most utilities, it also accepts `--` to signify the end of options](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02), even if there's no option that POSIX specifies for `basename`. You use it for `basename -- -file-.jpg .jpg` or in `basename -- "$file"` when you can't guarantee `$file` won't start with `-`.</sup>

Comment: ... and with GNU `find`, `-printf` can be used to get the same result without using `basename` at all.

Comment: GNU `find` could provide the basename of the file without running an external command, `-printf "%f\n"`. From the man: Print the basename; the file's name with any
                     leading directories removed (only the last
                     element).

Comment: The answer is now community wiki. Improve it at will.